# Practical example for (conditional) ignorability in potential outcomes

Tags: causality, exchangeability

Within the potential outcomes framework (Rubin Causal Model), I find that most sources efficiently explain ignorability and conditional ignorability algebraically. As far as I can tell, some use "exchangeability" as a synonymous term. While this is conceptually ok to me, I have to revisit the material from time to time. I often get a deeper understanding by working through every step of a process e.g., with toy samples. I wonder if anyone has input on where I may find a source explaining this step-by-step or may show by example how this is done with the data below.

Consider the effect of a cancer drug $D\in\{0,1\}$ on mortality $Y\in\{0,1\}$. All individuals have two potential outcomes:

- $Y_i^1=$ potential outcome if $D=1$
- $Y_i^0=$ potential outcome if $D=0$

All individuals only realize one of the potential outcomes, while the other is the unobserved counterfactual. If we could observe both potential outcomes, we could easily calculate the individual level causal effect (ICE), $\psi$, as:

$ICE=\psi=Y_i^1-Y_i^0$.

Because we can't observe both outcomes, we rely on the population average of ICE, i.e., the average causal effect (ACE):

$ACE=E[\psi]=E[Y_i^1]-E[Y_i^0]$.

Now, to make this concrete. Patients with cancer are randomized to $D$, and we have the following data:

| ID | D | Y | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Here $E[Y_i^1]=3/5=.6$ and $E[Y_i^0]=4/5=.8$, giving

$ACE=E[\psi]=.6-.8=-.2$

Thus, if everyone took treatment relative to none, the population level mortality rate would be reduced by .2.

Causal interpretation of this estimate rely on ignorability being true, i.e., the potential outcomes must be jointly independent of the treatment status,

$(Y_i^1,Y_i^0) \perp D$

Moreover, it would be helpful to extend this example to conditional ignorability, which causal inference from observational data rely on. In this case, say $X$ is whether patient has severe disease (stage 4) $(=1)$ or not $(=0)$, and that conditional ignorability holds when controlling for $X$,

$(Y_i^1,Y_i^0) \perp D| X$

My two main questions are:

1. How would one examine ignorability from the data above?
2. How would one examine conditional ignorability from the data above?

I have started to work out probabilities and conditional probabilities, but as I am somewhat uncertain about the complete procedure for (conditional) ignorability, I won't extend the post.

Comment: What do mean by "examine"? You cannot assess ignorability from observed data because it is an assumption that involves potential outcomes, which are not included in your table. I'm unclear on what you're asking for.